# Get git repo name and github username inside BASH script?

Tags: git, bash, github

I'm trying to create a bash script to open a Github pull request in a browser window.

Here's the command I need to run:

---

open https://github.com/ParentOwner/**RepoName**/compare/**develop**...**JoshuaSoileau**:**CurrentBranch**

---

Where the things in bold need to be dynamic.

I need to figure out how to pull the following things in BASH:

```
RepoName       -   name of the repo
develop        -   ARGUMENT to my bash script
JoshuaSoileau  -   github username of the current user
CurrentBranch  -   name of the currently checked out git branch.
```

I know how to do the following:

```
RepoName       -   ??
develop        -   $1 argument in my bash script
JoshuaSoileau  -   ??
CurrentBranch  -   $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

---

**How do I pull the `1. RepoName` and `2. Current github username` in a BASH script?**

This is what I have so far:

```
git-open-merge() {
    open https://github.com/ParentOwner/??/compare/$1...??:$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
}
```

And it's called like this:

```
git-open-merge develop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
git config --get-regexp user.name
```

For the **user name**. for the **repository name**, you may have different repositories with different names, so I guess parsing :

```
git remote get-url origin
```

could help if you only care about the origin ? The format would be (prefixes would differ between ssh or https) `git@github.com:{github_handle}/{repo_name}.git`

Answer (score 0):

To get the repo name in a bash script I do:

```
git config --get remote.origin.url | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev | cut -d. -f1
```

Explanation:

1. `git config --get remote.origin.url` returns something like
   `git@github.com:my-project/my-repo-name.git`
2. `rev` reverses the string
3. `cut -d/ -f1` cuts the string on the `/` then gets the first field (really the last one when in original order)
4. `rev` again to put the order back
5. `cut -d. -f1` to get just the repo name and not the `.git`